# DB error after upgrading to Playa 444: Duplicate column name 'parent_var_id'

Tags: playa, error, upgrade

After updating an EE 2.5.5 site to the latest playa 4.4.4., an error showed up when trying to access the FieldType settings screen.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1060
>
> Duplicate column name 'parent_var_id'
>
> ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_var_id INT(6) UNSIGNED
>   AFTER parent_row_id, ADD INDEX (parent_var_id)
>
> Filename:
>   [redacted]/playa/ft.playa.php
>
> Line Number: 423

I was in the process of upgrading the site to EE 2.6.1. so I carried on and the error still shows after performing the upgrade. It seems that the site is still functional, I see no error when accessing pages making use of playa or when using the fieldtype in the CP.

Anyone experienced this? P&T guys?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The guys at P&T did come back to me in less than 24 hours with a fix. I'll post it here in case someone runs into the same problem.

> Take a look at the columns in exp_playa_relationships table in the
>   database.
>
> - Does it have a field parent_var_id? If no, then the version you should set is 4.1.
> - If yes, does it have a field parent_is_draft? If no, then the version you should set is 4.3
> - If yes, then the version you should set is 4.4.4
>
> Now, set the version number we determined in the previous three steps
>   for the Playa field in the exp_fieldtypes table and go visit the
>   Add-ons -> Fieldtypes -> Playa page and hit submit.
>
> Everything should be all working now.

Comment: Just got hit with this as well, thanks for posting the solution.

Comment: No problem, Andris was quick on that one ;o)

Comment: I just got this too, upgrading from 4.0.5 -> 4.4.4 so I got worried before I saw this :)

Comment: Hey Rob! Glad it helped!

Comment: a life saver - just upgraded to playa 4.4.4

Comment: Happened to me again upgrading to EE 2.9.3 and Playa 4.5.2. I just manually updated the "exp_fieldtype" table "version" column to 4.5.2 and refreshed the CP page, the hit submit and everything is fine.

Comment: For those less knowledgable about MySQL, and since I got stuck with this today as well: The correct MySQL table to update is exp_fieldtypes:

update exp_fieldtypes set version='4.5.2' where name='playa' limit 1;

Comment: Updating the exp_fieldtypes table is what the answer suggest. Wasn't that clear to you? Should I be editing the answer to make it clearer?