# Database Error when upgrading Playa

Tags: ee2, playa, pixelandtonic

I've been performing an ExpressionEngine upgrade from v2.5 to 2.9.2. Everything seems to be going well except for the db error I get when upgrading playa. Playa appears to be working, but I get the error when I click on the playa link in the "Addons/Fieltypes/Playa". Not a major deal, but very interested in finding out why I'm getting error below.

---

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1060

Duplicate column name 'parent_var_id'

ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_var_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AFTER parent_row_id, ADD INDEX (parent_var_id)

Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php

### Line Number: 426

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: Hey, Mark. Here are two answers that will probably help: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/11994 and http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/24657

Comment: Yup... That fixed it for me. Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.