# DB Error after Playa upgrade in EE2.10

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, error, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I had an error after upgrading and fixed is as suggested in [right here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11970/db-error-after-upgrading-to-playa-444-duplicate-column-name-parent-var-id).

In this thread, the issue seems fixed, but for me, not just yet. Now I've got a similar, but not the same, error:

```
Error Number: 1060

Duplicate column name 'parent_element_id'

ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_element_id VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER parent_var_id

Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php

Line Number: 488
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they mentioned in the thread, there's a certain amount of things to be checked. If this then, that.

In my case, I had to check if there's a parent_element_id in exp_playa_relationships and, if so, change version to 4.5.2 in exp_fieldtypes.

These checks do feel somewhat more complex though, as you can just change the version to whatever version you're trying to install (which you can see in the Add-Ons -> Fieldtype tab)